# How do I offset mouse position so that I can centre paragraphs when the user clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, offset, mouse-position

I am creating an interactive website where the user is able to click anywhere on the page and each paragraph will show up one by one. At the moment the paragraphs are displaying to the right of the click but i want the paragraph to be centred on the mouse position. Is there a way to do this?

Is there also a way to restrict the paragraphs from going off the screen as this creates a landscape scroll which i don't want, Any help would be appreciated.

```
const texts = [
  "Paragraph: 1",
  "Paragraph: 2",
  "Paragraph: 3",
  "Paragraph: 4",
  "Paragraph: 5",
  "Paragraph: 6",
  "Paragraph: 7",
  "Paragraph: 8",
  "Paragraph: 9",
  "Paragraph: 10"
];
const classes = [
  "red gray-bg font-1",
  "blue font-2",
   "red",
  "blue",
   "red",
  "blue",
   "red",
  "blue",
   "red",
  "blue",
  
];
// Keeps Track of Current Text
let currentParaIdx = 0;

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // Stop once All Texts are Displayed
  if (currentParaIdx === texts.length) return;

  const { clientX, clientY } = e; //get the click position

  //create the div
  const div = document.createElement("div");

  //set its text
  div.innerText = texts[currentParaIdx];


  //set its position and position style
  div.classList=classes[currentParaIdx];
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.left = clientX + "px";
  div.style.top = clientY + "px";
  currentParaIdx++;
  document.body.append(div); //add div to the page
});
```

This is the code I have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Notes

While there isn't anything wrong with your code, there are a few things that could be changed that should make things a little more optimized and easier to manage your code going forward.

The first is your two arrays for the text and classes. Creating one array of objects would allow you to only have to work with one array, and you can pull whichever key/property you need depending on what you are doing.

Another thing is using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of string concatenation when setting some of your values. This is a small thing, but typically a good idea to do.

### Solution

Essentially, if you want to center an element on your mouse/cursor position, you need to move it by half of the elements `width` and `height`. In this situation, we are working with an element that is being dynamically created and so it initially will not have a `width` or `height`. We can add it to the document first, pull those values and then adjust the `top` and `left` properties accordingly. And because JavaScript is processed synchronously, this won't be noticeable to the user.

```js
const paragraphs = [
  {text: `Paragraph: 1`, class: "red gray-bg font-1"},
  {text: `Paragraph: 2`, class: "blue font-2"},
  {text: `Paragraph: 3`, class: "red"},
  {text: `Paragraph: 4`, class: "blue"},
  {text: `Paragraph: 5<br>Different sized paragraph`, class: "red"},
  {text: `Paragraph: 6<br><br><br>Another different sized paragraph`, class: "blue"},
  {text: `Paragraph: 7 | This is a wider paragraph`, class: "red"},
  {text: `Paragraph: 8 | This is also wider but max-width prevents this paragraph from becoming too wide`, class: "blue"},
  {text: `Paragraph: 9`, class: "red"},
  {text: `Paragraph: 10`, class: "blue"}
]

let currentParaIdx = 0

document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if(currentParaIdx === paragraphs.length) return

  const { clientX, clientY } = e,
  div = document.createElement("div")

  div.innerHTML = paragraphs[currentParaIdx].text
  div.className = `${paragraphs[currentParaIdx].class} paragraph`
  currentParaIdx++
  document.body.append(div)

  // Once the div is added, we can get its computed size
  // Then calculate if it will go off screen or not
  let bodyW = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.body).width),
      bodyH = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.body).height),
      divW = parseInt(getComputedStyle(div).width),
      divH = parseInt(getComputedStyle(div).height),
      divX = (clientX - Math.round(divW / 2) < 0) ? 0 : (clientX + Math.round(divW / 2) > bodyW) ? bodyW - (divW * 1.1) : clientX - Math.round(divW / 2),
      divY = (clientY - Math.round(divH / 2) < 0) ? 0 : (clientY + Math.round(divH / 2) > bodyH) ? bodyH - (divH * 1.1) : clientY - Math.round(divH / 2)
  
  div.style.left = `${divX}px`
  div.style.top = `${divY}px`
})
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.paragraph {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: default;
}

.red { color: #F00; }
.blue { color: #00F; }

.gray-bg { background: #CCC; }

.font-1 { font-size: 1em; }
.font-2 { font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: bold; }
```

### Additional Notes

I opted to use `getComputedStyle()` here instead of something like `getBoundingClientRect()` when getting things like the `width` and `height` because things like `padding` on an element can make these values inaccurate. Not knowing the full context of how this will be used, I felt it was a safer choice.

#### Edit

To answer a comment, as I need to use backticks and Stack Overflow code formatting will interfere, I'm adding this here:

```
div.style.top = `${clientY + window.scrollY}px`
```

Basically you wrap the entire value in backticks, And any JavaScript variables need to be wrapped in `${}`. All other text can be placed inside normally, but this way you don't need to use things like the `+` operator to concatenate multiple strings.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for answering, this code makes so much more sense however I tried copying and pasting this into a brand new document to test it but nothing seems to be appearing, any idea as to why that would be?

Comment: @SophieO'Mullan There are several potential reasons so I can't give you a guaranteed answer but I can give a few suggestions. One common issue is when people add the JavaScript too early in their code (for example, in the `<head>` tag). This causes the JavaScript to run too soon so typically you want to add JavaScript right before the closing `</body>` tag. Another thing to check would be the browser's console `F12` to see if any errors are occuring, which can help point to what needs to change/be fixed.

Comment: perfect thanks, how would I set out div.style.top = (clientY + window.scrollY) + "px"; in the format you suggested?

Comment: @SophieO'Mullan Unfortunately Stack Overflow comment formatting interferes with me needing to use backticks (*the little apostrophe-like character beside the `1` key*), but I did make an edit to my post to show how that code could be formatted using template literals (*along with a short explaination*).

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely use this method from now on, perfect explanation

Answer (score 0):

You could use [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) to center the element at your mouse position. Like clientX - half of your element's width.

And the other thing, I think this is what you need: [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution could be to add some CSS to the paragraph which you're rendering by using the CSS transform property.

Add the following CSS to the div:

```css
div {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This will visually move the div left by half it's width and up by half it's height from it's set position, essentially centring it on it's position.

Then, to fix the issue of the landscape scrolling, a rule could be added to prevent landscape overflow like below:

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```